# Sum of two Cosine functions is periodic.

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I wish to show that the sum of two cosine functions $\cos(a_{1}x+b_{1})$ and $\cos(a_{2}x+b_{2})$ is periodic ($a_{1},a_{2}\neq0$) where both functions are non-zero with their sum also being non-zero.

Well I know this statement itself is incorrect but I wish to specify that periods of both functions are of course rationals and are given by $\displaystyle T_{1}=\frac{2k\pi}{a_{1}}$ for an integer $k$ and $\displaystyle T_{2}=\frac{2n\pi}{a_{2}}$ for an integer $n$. Well, summing their periods would result in :
$$
T_{1}+T_{2}=\frac{2ka_{2}\pi+2na_{1}\pi}{a_{1}+a_{2}}=\frac{2\pi(ka_{2}+na_{1})}{a_{1}+a_{2}}
$$
I believe to complete this proof, I must state something about $ka_{2}+na_{1}$ I would hope if someone could assist me on this proof.

Comment: Suppose that one function is $2$-periodic and the other is $3$-periodic. Then their sum is $6$-periodic, not $5$-periodic.

Comment: . I think what must be shown is that the period of the sum must be the smallest lcm.

Comment: To make the above more precise: Suppose $f(x+2)=f(x)$ and $g(x+3)=g(x)$ for all $x$. Let $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Then $f(x+6)=f(x+4)=f(x+2)=f(x)$ and $g(x+6)=g(x+3)=g(x)$, so $h(x+6)=h(x)$. By contrast, the same manipulations give $f(x+5)=f(x+1)\neq f(x)$ and $g(x+5)=g(x+2)\neq g(x)$, so $h(x+5)\neq h(x)$.

Comment: So what we want is that $f(x+c)=f(x)$ and $g(x+c)=g(x)$  imply that $h(x+c)=f(x+c)+g(x+c)=f(x)+g(x)$ I see that the period here must depend on the value of $\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}$ but what argument proves that this ratio is rational. Perhaps this proposed property has more counterexamples than I can count but there must be an important condition for it to work. @Semiclassical

Comment: I am now aware of these counter examples, but how could we fix this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is for the ratio $\ \frac{a_1}{a_2}\ $ to be rational. If $\ \frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{k_1}{k_2}\ $, where $\ k_1,k_2\ $ are relatively prime integers, then
$$
T=\frac{2\pi k_1}{a_1}=\frac{2\pi k_2}{a_2}\\
$$
is a period of both $\ \cos\big(a_1x+b_1\big)\ $ and $\ \cos\big(a_2x+b_2\big)\ $, and hence a period of $\ \cos\big(a_1x+b_1\big)+\cos\big(a_2x+b_2\big)\ $:
\begin{align}
\cos\big(a_1(x+nT)&+b_1\big)+\cos\big(a_2(x+nT)+b_2\big)\\
&=\cos\left(a_1\left(x+\frac{2\pi nk_1}{a_1}\right)+b_1\right)+\\
&\hspace{6em}\cos\left(a_2\left(x+\frac{2\pi nk_2}{a_2}\right)+b_2\right)\\
&=\cos\big(a_1x+b_1+2\pi nk_1\big)+\cos\big(a_2x+b_2+2\pi nk_2\big)\\
&=\cos\big(a_1x+b_1\big)+\cos\big(a_2x+b_2\big)
\end{align}